# Как в ASP.NET MVC отображать несколько результатов в представлении?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Как передать в представлении несколько результатов? Например, у меня есть связанные таблицы один ко многим, 1 главная таблица `Kolledjlist` - с названиями колледжей, когда нажимается "просмотр" отображается подробная информация о текущем колледже через `id`:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Prosmotr", "Detail", new { id = item.Id })
```

В представлении `Detail` загружается таблица со специальностями выбранного колледжа:

```
public ActionResult Detail(int? id){
return View(db.Speslists.Where(c => c.KolledjlistId == id).ToList());}
```

Хочу, чтобы рядом со специальностями в другой блоке `<div>` отображалась паспортные данные из таблицы `Informs`, спортивные секции из таблицы `Sections`, все таблицы связаны с таблицей `Kolledjlist` через `KolledjlistId`.

```
public ActionResult Detail(int? id){
return View(db.Speslists.Where(c => c.KolledjlistId == id).ToList());}
```

Пробовал `ViewBag` не работает:

```
public ActionResult Detail(int? id){
ViewBag.Inform = db.Informs.Where(i => i.KolledjlistId == id).ToList());
return View(db.Speslists.Where(c => c.KolledjlistId == id).ToList());}
```

Если можно напишите пример, как здесь передать несколько результатов из разных таблицы в один `View`. Уже третий день голову ломаю, так и не нашел выход(
создал новый класс

```
`public Kolledjlist College { get; set; } public IEnumerable<Speslists> Speslists { get; set; } public IEnumerable<Dops> Dops { get; set; }`
```

В контроллере прописал

```
`Class1 model = new Class1() { 
 Speslists = db.Speslists.Where(c => c.KolledjlistId == id).ToList(), 
Dops = db.Dops.Where(i => i.KolledjlistId == id).ToList() }; 
return View(model);`
```

в View добавил

```
     `@model IEnumerable <AbitV2.Models.Class1>     
  <div>
        @foreach (AbitV2.Models.Class1 m in Model)
            {
            <h4>@Html.DisplayFor(model => m.Speslists)</h4>
        }`
```

ничего не выходит. в "m.Speslists." не отображается столбцы таблицы. Что то не так делаю?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Model_College
{
  public Kolledjlist College { get; set; }
  public IEnumerable<Speslists> Programs  { get; set; }
  public IEnumerable<Informs> Informs { get; set; } 
  ...
}

public ActionResult Detail(int? id)
{
  Model_College model = new Model_College() 
  {
    College = ...,
    Programs = db.Speslists.Where(c => c.KolledjlistId == id).ToList(),
    Informs = db.Informs.Where(i => i.KolledjlistId == id).ToList()
    ...
  }
  return View(model);
}
```

*Update*

```
 @model AbitV2.Models.Class1     
 <div>
    @foreach (Speslists s in Model.Speslists)
    {
        <h4>@s.Name</h4>
    }
```

Comment: создал новый класс public Kolledjlist College { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Speslists> Speslists { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Dops> Dops { get; set; },  В контроллере прописал Class1 model = new Class1()
            {
                // College = db.Kolledjlists();
                Speslists = db.Speslists.Where(c => c.KolledjlistId == id).ToList(),
                Dops = db.Dops.Where(i => i.KolledjlistId == id).ToList()
            };
  return View(model);

Comment: Молодец! Не останавливайтесь на достигнутом.